# C++ rename an overloaded function

Tags: c++, macros

Is it possible to rename a function that takes a certain number of arguments?

I tried to use #define like this:

```
#define move(arg1, arg2, arg3) move_old(arg1, arg2, arg3)

#include <bits/stl_algobase.h>

#undef move(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

But it does not work.
There is also a function std::move that takes one agument and I don't want it to be renamed.
I have to do so because I have to replace the bits/stl_algobase.h functionality function by function.

Comment: Are you using `using namespace std;`?  If you are don't and that should fix the problem.

Comment: [You *need* it to be renamed, or you think renaming it will solve something else?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I still need to use std::move that receive a single argument

Comment: I need to rename it because I have to reimplement it and I need that just std::move (3 arguments) to be renamed such that I don't have a name conflict

Comment: @yonutix Then you use `std::move(for, bar, baz)` instead of `move(for, bar, baz)` and then the compile knows which one you want.

Comment: _I have to replace the bits/stl_algobase.h functionality_ I am sure you have not.

Comment: @manni66, yes I have to replace it function by function. I understand that you don't think that I really need to do this, but in my case I need to do so because I need the function to be compliant with a certain ISO

Comment: @yonutix Then make your own copy of that header. System functions are not designed to be replaced.

Comment: @cdhowie, I thought I can do something simple, until now I used #define and #undef, but now I encounter function overloading

Comment: You can't, you are violating the ODR.

Comment: @yonutix What makes you think that replacing part of the C++ standard library is "simple?"

Comment: Ok, I was asking if it's possible, @cdhowie, I did not say that

Comment: If you're just replacing the functions one-by-one, you should be putting your replacements in a different namespace, not trying to put your own implementations under std. Once they are in a different namespace you can easily change each usage to use your version instead.

Comment: The clients want them under std

Comment: Usually when clients ask me to do something silly, the first thing I do is to educate the client on why what they actually want is not what they seem to think they want...

Comment: @Sean Burton, In this way the client can develop the application with the old standard and then just replace the libraries

Comment: @yonutix Do note that besides added template specializations for custom types you cannot ass things into `std`.  Doing so is undefined behavior.

Comment: @yonutix "The clients want them under std" - then you need to educate your clients. As @NathanOliver points out, you are entering UB territory if you do anything to the `std` namespace *except* adding template specialisations to it.  I'm sure your clients won't enjoy random crashes or weird behaviour, so better steer clear of that.

Comment: Can you replace the file?

Comment: Btw, you do know that `std::move` is in fact nothing more than a cast to rvalue..?

Comment: Seeing as your goal is to be compliant with a particular ISO, I doubt it will allow undefined behaviour. What your client is asking for is self-contradicting

Comment: Even if you use tricks like this to rename stuff at compile-time you're going to have a hard time when you come to link your application against any standard C++ runtime which will contain all the functions under their original names

Comment: "I have to do so because I have to replace the bits/stl_algobase.h functionality function by function" ...but, I presume, you probably don't in doing so want to mess up the behavior of e.g. `std::char_traits<T>::move`, right?  (If you had a macro that renamed `move` with 3 arguments only to `move_old`, you'd be mucking this up).

Comment: @H Walters I would not because I would define a move function of my own

Comment: @Sean Burton: In the end there will be no standard c++ library to link with, just this library we're working on

Comment: @yonutix "I would define a move function of my own" You're missing the point.  `char_traits`'s `move`'s have nothing to do with `algorithm`'s `move`'s; they are different features, doing different things in different namespaces.  The only thing they have in common is that they involve something called `move` that accepts 3 arguments.  Your approach, however, can't tell the difference, since _all_ the preprocessor would know is that something is called `move` and has 3 arguments.  The point is that the preprocessor is the wrong tool for the job.